# Ruby filter for a Trolls messages in the Chat (fill array with repeat values)

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

In chat where I use to be a couple of trolls lives, I cannot move them away, and I tired to listen their songs. I write a code to change trolls messages into `croack croak` frog sound.

Like this. `"You are dirty sucks. Monkey code. Lamer."` =>  `"cro cro croak croakc croakc croak croakc"`

For this I use some code, and I fill the word of a troll by `croak` is some verbose manner `x.chars.zip(%w{c r o a k}.cycle).map{|x,y| y}.join`. **How to fill array with repetitive value more concise way?**

Here is a code, I'm using:

```
def troll_filter message
    message.split(" ")
    .map{ |x| 
        x.chars.zip(%w{c r o a k}.cycle).map{|x,y| y}.join 
    }.join(" ")
end

p troll_filter "sucks sucks" # "croak croak"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd maybe use [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-gsub) to change just text, not punctuation. Also, no need to `map` - just need to know the `size`:

```
def troll_filter(message)
  message.gsub(/\p{Word}+/) { |x| "croak".each_char.cycle.take(x.size).join }
end

# => "cro cro croak croak. croakc croa. croak."
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `\w` equals only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If you want to capture other chars you might want to consider using `[[:alnum:]]` instead. This also captures non-ascii characters like `é`. Thus changing the regex to `/[[:alnum:]]+/`. See: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Character+Classes